# When I set transaction isolation level in code, is it enforced in code or in DBMS?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, isolation-level

If I make a call like this in Java code:

> connection.setTransactionIsolation(Connection.TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ);

is this enforced in code, by DBMS table/row-level locks, or either of those depending on the JDBC driver implementation?

Thanks!

Comment: It should be `Connection.TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ` not `Connection.READ_REPEATABLE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isolation level is enforced by the database engine, not application code.

Here is a good resource on the subject if you are interested.  [Isolation Levels](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc546518.aspx)

Comment: How do you know Jan is using SQL Server?

Comment: I don't, but that doesn't really change the answer, and offering more information on the subject doesn't hurt.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the JDBC API which rely on the underlying JDBC driver implementation which rely on underlying RDBMS :

> A JDBC driver might not support all transaction isolation levels. If a driver does not support the isolation level specified in an invocation of setTransactionIsolation, the driver can substitute a higher, more restrictive transaction isolation level. If a driver cannot substitute a higher transaction level, it throws a SQLException. Use the method DatabaseMetaData.supportsTransactionIsolationLevel to determine whether or not the driver supports a given level.

If you were using JTA API you would rely on underlying implementation fulfilling a JCA contract. The contract would also be implemented by the RDBMS in the case of relational database resource but could definitely be implemented differently (eg. using code) for a resource of another type (a JMS one for example).